# MacOS Flutter in VSCode and Xcode not opening or responding

Tags: flutter, xcode, macos, performance

When I try to open Xcode, it immediately says that it is not responding. I have tried completely uninstalling it and reinstalling it to my system, but it didn't do anything. It is extremely slow to launch (usually it takes seconds on this M2 chip), and usually gets stuck on the blank loading screen of the Xcode file I am trying to open.

Now, in addition to the Xcode problem, when I try to run my flutter application on Android Studio OR iOS simulator, it is either taking so long that I just stop it or it just doesn't get past 'launching lib/main.dart'. I thought this was with the new stuff I implemented in a branch of my project, but when I reverted back to the older commits it still wasn't launching. Again, it usually took about 5-10 seconds to launch and build on either simulators.

The iOS and Android simulators themselves all launch perfectly, it is just that my app can't be launched or installed on it. I guess this is a VSCode or Xcode error.

Also, it is probably worth noting, but while clearing storage on my MacBook I removed Xcode caches and builds to help increase storage.

I don't know if this is a slowdown or something (which it shouldn't be because this is a new M2 MacBook Air).

Any help would be appreciated.